# Rails, "respond_to do |format|" returns ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run some javascript straight from my controller.

I have already created my JS file in **views/articles/create.js.erb**

In my **articles_controller**:

```
def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        if @article.save && manage_strings
            @status = 'success'
        else
            @status = 'error'
            @errormessages= @article.errors.full_messages
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end

end
```

When I run my app the **respond_to do |format|** gives me **ActionController::UnknownFormat**

I tried updating my **mime_types.rb** with the following line and restarting my server as suggested somewhere else, but to no results:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/javascript", :js
```

The wierd thing is that in my **languages_controller** the following works perfectly with my js file in **views/languages/list.js.erb**.

```
def list
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

Any ideas or suggestions regarding what could be at fault here?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The controller code seems OK, the problem may be with the request. Can you include the `Processing ..` and `Parameters:` lines from your `log/development.log`?

Comment: @dyserone Your if-else conditions should be inside your respond_to block. See my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: for that create request must be ajax(xhr) request not html.

Comment: guys thank you it actually was as max suggested. Really damn simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the request is not requesting JS. In order for rails to treat the request as JS the path needs to end with `.js` or have the correct `Accept` or `Content-Type` headers. Not that the mime type is not registered with rails as it registers the most common mime-types for javascript.

1. Check the rails log to confirm: `tail -f logs/development.log`
2. Check the browser console for errors.
3. Check that form that is has the `data-remote="true"` attribute.

---

```
<%= form_for(@thing, remote: true) %>
```

Comment: I cant believe that my problem was that simple, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your create action be something like this?

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save && manage_strings
      format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @article.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Your answer seems more complete and is a good practice to follow. Sorry for not picking yours but the particular problem was solved by max's answer. 
Also, I am trying to load a js file, would "format.json" work too?